# In The Rolling Stones, who put the note on the bicycles in the name of the Galactic Overlord?

Tags: robert-a-heinlein, the-rolling-stones

In Robert Heinlein's novel *The Rolling Stones*, when Mr. Stone retrieves the bicycles he'd jettisoned from the spaceship, he finds a note on them signed by the Galactic Overlord, a fictional character from the space opera Mr. Stone writes.  Mr. Stone is puzzled, since nobody had the opportunity to place the note there.  Who put that note on the bicycles, and when?

Comment: *Are you doubting the existence of the Galactic Overlord!?*

Comment: @Paulie_D: I don't, but I don't understand how he could have hidden in the spaceship or otherwise access the bicycles.

Comment: The Galactic Overlord was, as I understand it, not only fictional but was multi-universal. He pops up in various guises in several later Heinlen books. So I guess he just popped out of one universe into another. It's all part of the "World as Myth" thing....erm... *I think*.

Comment: In any case, although Hazel denies writing it, it seems likely that when she turns up rejeuvenated in *The Cat who Walks Through Walls* and starts time and universe hopping that she **would** have written it just to mess with him.